I have a painterly node group with brush direction input. I would like to be able to randomise across the model instead of being uniform please
I have managed to obtain a node group for a painterly style material which is close to perfection. However the brush stroke direction which is controlled is completely uniform. I would like to basically randomise the direction some more so each stroke direction is randomised and not completely uniform with the rest.
I have tried using noise/voronois but cannot get the results. I am not very good at maths so I haven't tried angles and such.
I have attached the blend file, the model, material and shader. Inside the shader I have put the node group in question on the far left. It is called 'psuedopainter' Inside the node group, everything is categorised and the input in question is top left, called 'brush direction'.
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1fCt8wvKNS7hRAIUf5IDY8nTXy8BwkuSq?usp=sharing
